# Using BeautifulSoup, how to get text only from the specific selector without the text in the children?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I don't know how to code `BeautifulSoup` so that it gives me only the text from the selected tag. I get more such as the text of its child(ren)!

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div id="left"><ul><li>"I want this text"<a href="someurl.com"> I don\'t want this text</a><p>I don\'t want this either</li><li>"Good"<a href="someurl.com"> Not Good</a><p> Not Good either</li></ul></div>', "html5lib") 
x = soup.select('ul > li')
for i in x:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

> "I want this text" I don't want this textI don't want this either
>
> "Good" Not Good Not Good either

Desired Output:

> "I want this text"
>
> "Good"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to get the first element of the [`contents` list](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
for i in x:
    print(i.contents[0])
```

Another - find the first *text node*:

```
for i in x:
    print(i.find(text=True))
```

Both would print:

```
"I want this text"
"Good"
```

Comment: The snippets must have been on standby again!

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div id="left"><ul><li>"I want this text"<a href="someurl.com"> I don\'t want this text</a><p>I don\'t want this either</li><li>"Good"<a href="someurl.com"> Not Good</a><p> Not Good either</li></ul></div>', "html5lib")
x = soup.select('ul > li')
for i in x:
    if isinstance(i.next_element, NavigableString):#if li's next child is a string
        print(i.next_element)
```